# prove that $(n+3)^{2}=\Theta(n-5)^{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, discrete-mathematics

I need to find $c_1,c_2,n_0>0$ so for all $n\geq n_0$:

$$c_{1}(n-5)^{2}\leq(n+3)^{2}\leq c_{2}(n-5)^{2}$$

I have problem with the right side of the inequality. I can't find c2.

thanks for any help :)

Comment: Set $c_2=2$ (or any number larger than $1$). Since $\frac{(n+3)^2}{(n-5)^2}$ decreases to $1$ as $n \to \infty$, there should be some $n_0$ such that $\frac{(n+3)^2}{(n-5)^2} \le c_2$ for $n \ge n_0$. Some trial and error should lead you to a valid $n_0$.

Comment: If you can use property of limits you don't even need to explicitly find these constants. You can show $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{(n+3)^2}{(n-5)^2} = 1$.

Comment: thank you for your help!